# @Html.ActionLink adding class and id

Tags: jquery, html, ajax, razor, asp.net-mvc-5

trying to add a class to an action link and id value, capture the class and pass the value to the controller.

I have this Jquery to capture the link click:

```
<script>
$(function () {
    $(".ActionLink").click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var newurl = $(this).attr("href");            
        console.log(newurl);
        $("#AddSection").load(newurl);            
    });
});
```

tried a few different ways without success.

First one is

```
@Html.ActionLink("Edit", "_EditGender1", new { id = item.GenderID })
```

which returns the html: `<a href="/Treeview/_EditGender1/1">Edit</a>`

obviously this one won't work but it assigned the id correctly to the end of the url /1

second one:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Edit", "_EditGender1", new { @class = "AddSection", id = item.GenderID })
```

which returns: `<a href="/Treeview/_EditGender1/1?class=AddSection">Edit</a>`

The id again is added correctly, but even though it has the class=AddSection the Jquery does not capture this.

```
 @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "_EditGender1", "Treeview", null, new { @class = "AddSection", id = item.GenderID })
```

returns: `<a class="AddSection" href="/Treeview/_EditGender1" id="1">Edit</a>`

This is captured by the Jquery correctly, but it isn't passing the id into the url and back to the controller.

Not sure what else to try!

Comment: `@Html.ActionLink("Edit", "_EditGender1", new {  id = item.GenderID }, new { @class = "AddSection" })` - refer [this overload](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd504988(v=vs.118).aspx)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`@Html.ActionLink` has an overload to add route values and html attributes.

```
@Html.ActionLink("Edit", "_EditGender1", new { id = item.GenderID }, new { @class = "AddSection" })
```

The 3rd parameter adds route values and the 4th parameter adds html attributes.

[Refer documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd504988(v=vs.118).aspx)